# React native App on android stops execution when device is locked and dormant

Tags: android, react-native

I created a reac-native android app that monitors changes in wifi environment and transmits them periodically to the cloud. The app usually runs in the background. However, several minutes after the device screen darkens and locks up the app stops running.

I'm aware of problems that occur when apps go into background and when screen is locked. I tried working around those by using two mechanisms:

1. using background timer [https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues]
2. using react native background task [(https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task]

I used them in the following manner:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.askForUserPermissions();
    this.getUserData();
    console.log("BackgroundTimer.setInterval");
    const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
      this.updateData();
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Registering Background Task");
    BackgroundTask.schedule();
  }
```

where updateData is function that checkss changes in wifi status (scanned networks,ssids,bssids, ip address etc.) and also updates state and posts the data to the cloud.

The background task code just posts data to the cloud via fetch & post.

Both mechanisms work very well when the device is unlocked but several minutes after the device is locked both stop working.

How can i make my app continue running even when device is dormant ?

Comment: I think this is happening because of the battery optimization features of newer Android versions. The only fix would be to ask the user to disable the battery optimization for your app by redirecting them to your app settings.

Comment: thanks moritzw. I've tried it and it seems to be working !!!

Comment: Moritzw!!! Not all heroes wear capes. Thanks <3